# how to alter output panel position in sublime2

Tags: plugins, ide, sublimetext2, preferences

After browsing enormous links , i cant still find how to alter the output panel of *Sublime 2 IDE*  . I need to move output panel to right side of screen. rather than seeing just few lines of output at the bottom of the screen. please help me.